# What is the cause of "SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" when using "npm start" for React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I had built a website (following an online tutorial) using create-react-app and using VSCode. The site's frontend had been working previously, but after installing mysql and mysql2 through npm, running "npm start" results in the following output:

```
> frontend@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start 

D:\react\connected-site\frontend\node_modules\react-dev-utils\node_modules\chalk\source\index.js:1      
$→��m��mo�L�D��;�%g�?w��ŷ↓�▬��ovH0��a�5��*�ؒ��l͛�S�iy☺�r�O7����%L]��%��∟�hk
 ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\react\connected-site\frontend\node_modules\react-dev-utils\chalk.js:10:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
```

The error seems to be unrelated to my index.js and app.js files or any imports (I've tested by commenting everything out) because it still occurs.

Could someone tell me what the source of the problem is and how to fix this?

- react version: 18.2.0
- mysql version: 2.18.1
- mysql2 version: 2.3.3
- node version: 16.16.0

If there are any other dependencies or info needed to resolve this, please leave a comment.

Comment: Do following, 1. delete `node_module` folder and `package.lock.json` 2. execute `npm install` 3. `npm start`. Also, check your current node version in terminal `node -v` use stable node version `nvm use 16.15.1`

Comment: After following your steps, everything worked on node version 16.16.0. Thank you. Do you think this issue was a bug in this current version of Node.js?

Comment: It would have because one or many npm package in your project require node version above the version in use in your machine for ex. above `14.x.x`.

Comment: Did you get any warning messages during `npm install` ?

Comment: No warnings during npm install.